How to enable .htaccess support with PHP-FPM, Nginx, and Apache2 on Ubuntu 24.04 with FastPanel?
I am currently running PHP-FPM with Nginx on my Ubuntu 24.04 server, managed through FastPanel. However, my .htaccess file is not working since .htaccess is not supported with Nginx alone. I want to set up the server to use PHP-FPM with both Nginx and Apache2 so that .htaccess can function properly.
I would like to integrate Apache2 into this setup to enable .htaccess functionality while keeping PHP-FPM and Nginx.
Can anyone provide guidance on how to configure this setup properly?
Thanks in advance!

If it's solely for this purpose, you'd be much better off just translating what your .htaccess file does into nginx's configuration. Installing two HTTP servers just to get .htaccess working is a bit odd.

"with both Nginx and Apache2" - why? Why not use one single server?

If you need to use both Nginx and Apache, then you will still need .htaccess, but you will need to set up an Nginx conf too. Here's a converter from htaccess: https://winginx.com/en/htaccess
And here's another one: https://www.getpagespeed.com/apache-to-nginx
If you only need to use Nginx, then you will not need .htaccess for effective usage, but nevertheless you can convert your .htaccess to Nginx-like code.

This is NOT an answer to the question. It should havebeen a comment.
